# Hints on evaluating this infinite sum

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can someone give some hints on how to evaluate this sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n+2}{n}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+2}$$

I came across this sum when I was solving a probability problem.

Comment: What was the problem? Perhaps there's an easier way to get the answer instead of reducing to an infinite sum?

Comment: $$\left(\frac23\right)^n\left(\frac13\right)^{n+2}=\frac19\left(\frac29\right)^n.$$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: $$\binom{2n+2}{n}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1},$$ and you might be able to use the generating function for the central binomial coefficients to get a value for this series.

Comment: Here it was solved for a general $K$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713734/evaluation-of-the-expression-sum-limits-n-0-infty142n-choosenp . For us, $K=2$, and the answer comes out to be $3/4$.

Comment: To add to @ThomasAndrews you may find something by simplifying the binomial coefficient using: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7778/proving-2n-choose-n-2n-frac-1-cdot-3-cdot-5-cdots-2n-1n

Comment: @Vercingetorix the problem is as follows: Consider an ant walking along the positive integers. At n, the ant moves to n+1 with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and to n−1 with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. If the ant reaches 0, it stops walking. Starting from n=3, what's the probability that the ant reaches n=5 before reaching n=0?

This problem can be easily solved using recursion, but I was just trying to solve it in a more 'combinatoric-ish' way. But now I think that my original sum is not correct. I overcounted : p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the generating function for the [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) we get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}x^{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1=f(x)$$

Now, $$\binom{2n+2}{n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$$ and $$\left(\frac23\right)^n\left(\frac13\right)^{n+2}=\frac12\left(\frac29\right)^{n+1}.$$

So your sum can be rewritten, with $x=2/9,$ as:

$$\frac12\sum_n \binom{2n+2}{n+1}x^{n+1} -\frac1{2x}\sum_n \frac1{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}x^{n+2}.$$

So if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ with $F(0)=0,$ this becomes:

$$\frac12f(2/9)-\frac94F(2/9).$$

Now $f(2/9)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-8/9}}-1=2.$

So now we just need an antiderivative for $f.$

We can show: $$F(x)=-\frac12(1-4x)^{1/2}-x+C.$$ Then $C=1/2,$ and $F(2/9)=-\frac16-\frac29+\frac12=\frac1{9}.$

So you get a result of $\frac34.$

Comment: Fixed the bad fraction computations.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the expected number of visits to state $-2$, starting from state $0$, in a random walk on $\{-2,-1,0,\dots\}$ with the following transition probabilities.  At state $-2$, you go to state $0$ with probability $1$; otherwise, you go up one unit with probability $2/3$ and down one unit with probability $1/3$.  Let $v_i$ be this expectation, given that you start at state $i$.  By first-step analysis (conditioning on the first step out of state $i$), we have $v_{-2}=1+v_0$ and
$$v_i = \frac{2}{3}v_{i+1} + \frac{1}{3}v_{i-1} \quad \text{for $i > -2$}$$
Now solve this recurrence, and you will find that $v_0=3/4$.

Comment: Good answer! How do you typically evaluate this recursion though? I'm aware of the general steps when you also have an upper bound but I'm not sure when you only have a lower bound to work with.

Comment: @Vercingetorix Generating functions are useful in cases like this.

Comment: Um, isn't it the expected number of times you reach $-2,$ for all time? Because it sums over all $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the corrected interpretation.  I  didn't work out the details, just gave hints, but the original sum is $3/4$.

Comment: Why is this an expectation? I was thinking ${2n+2 \choose n}(2/3)^{n}(1/3)^{n+2}$ just gave the probability of reaching $-2$ in exactly $2n+2$ steps ($n$ ups and $n+2$ downs and ${2n+2 \choose n}$ ways that could happen), and as you sum over all $n$ you'd be find the probability of reaching $-2$ in *any* $2n+2$ steps, i.e, prob of reaching $-2$ at some point. if it was expectation then you would have a factor of $n$ there in each summand.

Comment: @Vercingetorix Because you are counting every possible round the probability on that round. So if $X_n$ is $1$ if you are at $-2$ in step $2n+2,$ and $0$ otherwise, then you are computing:  $$E(X_0+X_1+X_2+\cdots).$$ To get the total probability of ever reaching $-2,$ you'd have to have $X_n$ bet $1$ if $n$ is the first round you reached $-2.$

Comment: Ah right. Good point.